# How to use offline w3.css

Tags: html, css

I downloaded two css files from https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css and https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-blue.css. When using them locally, somehow they cannot work(i.e. cannot reflect the desired output).

(Desired output)Using online css:
[online result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6WLi.png)

html code using online css :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-blue.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<body class="w3-theme-l4">

<div style="min-width:400px">

<div class="w3-bar w3-large w3-theme-d2">
  <span class="w3-bar-item">UpLevel Admin</span>
</div>
<div class="w3-bar w3-medium w3-theme-d2">
  <a href="options.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Categories</a>
  <a href="level.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Level</a>
  <a href="progress.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Progress</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="w3-bar-item w3-btn"><img src="images/admin_math.png"><span class="caption">Math</span></div>
  <div class="w3-bar-item w3-btn"><img src="images/languages.png"><span class="caption">Languages</span></div>
  <div class="w3-bar-item w3-btn"><img src="images/sat.png"><span class="caption">SAT</span></div>
  <div class="w3-bar-item w3-btn" onclick="location.href='progress.html';"><img src="images/coding.png"><span class="caption">Coding</span></div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

===================================================

Using offline css:
[offline result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdlKg.png)

html code using offline css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3-theme-blue.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<body class="w3-theme-l4">

<div style="min-width:400px">

<div class="w3-bar w3-large w3-theme-d2">
  <span class="w3-bar-item">UpLevel Admin</span>
</div>
<div class="w3-bar w3-medium w3-theme-d2">
  <a href="category.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Categories</a>
  <a href="level.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Level</a>
  <a href="progress.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Progress</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="w3-bar-item w3-btn"><img src="math.png"><span class="caption">Math</span></div>
  <div class="w3-bar-item w3-btn"><img src="languages.png"><span class="caption">Languages</span></div>
  <div class="w3-bar-item w3-btn"><img src="sat.png"><span class="caption">SAT</span></div>
  <div class="w3-bar-item w3-btn" onclick="location.href='progress.html';"><img src="coding.png"><span class="caption">Coding</span></div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your folder structure so we can see where your css is located relative to your html?

Comment: all files are within the same directory. e.g. folder/w3.css; folder/mypage.html; folder/w3-theme-blue.css

Comment: Did you try hard refreshing your browser? CTRL + r or CTRL + F5

Comment: I just tried it locally and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is maybe, the level of hierarchy of your files and folders where you are keeping your CSS stylesheet.

Make sure to place your CSS files at the same hierarchy (in the same project folder)

**Note: The files shouldn't be any folder because your math is absolute and will work at the same level only.
And Make sure of any typos you may have done to the file names**

Comment: Yes. all files are within the same folder. e.g. folder/w3.css; folder/mypage.html; folder/w3-theme-blue.css

Comment: Had you checked whether the css stylesheet is working or not?